# Shortener wont work with Facebook link

Tags: facebook, laravel, redirect

I my app I have a shortener. For example `www.example.com/Asy` redirects to `www.facebook.com/id`

if someone share that link on a Facebook page, Facebook somehow passes my URL and directly puts the link to Facebook, so in that case when someone clicks on that link on Facebook I can't track number of clicks.

The code I am using is like this:

```
public function redirect($uri){
    $link = Link::where('uri',$uri);
    // Save number of click in database
    return Redirect::to($link->real_url);
}
```

And if I want to redirect to `google.com` everything is fine but Facebook page on Facebook timeline don't work.

It works if someone put that link on Twitter, first get to my app and then redirect to Facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like Facebook follows the redirect, realises it is pointed to itself - and keeps the user inside Facebook. You could maybe try and detect who is visiting your page, and see if it is a facebook crawler, and trick it into allowing the link

```
public function redirect($uri){
    if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], array(
      'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)',
      'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'
    ))) 
    {
      // It is probably a Facebook bot
      // So put a fake page here.
      // Note - dont redirect this fake link - or FB might follow the fake link
      return View::make('fake.page');
    }
    else {
      //that's not Facebook - so show the real link
      $link = Link::where('uri',$uri);
      // Save number of click in database
      return Redirect::to($link->real_url);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook links parsing has changed it's behaviour some time ago. It now follows HTTP redirects until final URL has been reached, and uses it to end clients instead. This is clearly visible when you debug your URL with [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

HTTP 301 redirect means "Permanent redirection". It's pretty much normal, that Facebook follows it - as this is what all browsers also do. E.g. if you'll insert a link in your browser, which uses 301 redirect to another page - first hit will be translated/recorded, following ones will have redirect without even hitting short URL service (if you use any).
To avoid browser auto-redirect, you should change HTTP status redirection behaviour from 301 to 302, which means "Temporary redirect". However, this won't solve Facebook problem.

The only way I succeeded forcing Facebook to display short URL with redirect instead of final one was by [publishing through Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#publishing), in combination with 302 status. Posts created through API still display the link as it was provided in data; however, as it's Facebook (doh!), there is no guarantee that their developers there will change behaviour and will start following redirects as well.

If you're using YOURLS shortener service, there is a great called "302-instead", which changes 301 redirects to 302.